# Flask template inheritance

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

In "templates" folder i have the "index.html" file and the "list.html" file:

"list.html":

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block list %}
<div>
  <h1>list</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

"index.html"(body):

```
<body>
  {% block list%}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

"app.py":

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and the problem is that only static part of index.html is rendering in the browser. There is no h1 tag with "list".

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend in the context of Flask means that your using "index.html" as template for "list.html", but this will not change "index.html". If you want to see your `<h1>` tag you have to render "list.html".